# ThreeJS triangulateShape returning null

Tags: three.js, triangulation

I am trying to create a custom shape using ThreeJS triangulateShape.

For example: if the points are: `["-1 0 1", "-1 0 -1", "1 0 -1", "1 0 1"]` a simple square, it should automatically create the faces formed by triangles: `["0 1 2", "0 2 3"]`.

I am trying to use the `shapeUtils.triangulateShape` function but it fails. The code looks like this:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var points = data.vertices.map(function (vertex) {
    return vertex.split(' ').map(function(x){return parseFloat(x);});
});
for(var i =0; i < points.length; i++) {
  geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(points[i][0], points[i][1], points[i][2]));
}
var holes =[];
var triangles = THREE.ShapeUtils.triangulateShape( geometry.vertices, holes );
```

It creates a null array. I guess something is wrong in passing the params to triangulateShape but cannot figure out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ShapeUtils.triangulateShape` only accepts a 2D contour as the first parameter. You are applying 3D data.

Comment: when I tried 

    var geom = new THREE.Geometry();
    var verts = [{ x:-1, y:1 }, { x:-1, y:-1 }, { x:1, y:-1 }, { x:-1, y:1 }];
    var holes =[];
    var triangles = THREE.ShapeUtils.triangulateShape( verts, holes );

it throws an error

Comment: I even tried changing the array to:

`["-1 1", "-1 -1", "1 -1", "1 1"]` 

it throws an error

Comment: Can you please be more precise? What kind of error? Can you post the error message? In any event, try to demonstrate the issue with a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/

Comment: Have created an example: https://jsfiddle.net/rajur/n2kapkn3/. The error it shows is: `TypeError: a[(b - 1)].equals is not a function at af (VM55 three.min.js:226)`. Thanks

Comment: You have to define your vertices as an array of `THREE.Vector2`: https://jsfiddle.net/n2kapkn3/1/

Comment: That did the trick. Many thanks @Mugen87. Would the holes too be Vector2 array? Will mark this as a solution.

Comment: It's an array of holes. A single hole is an array of `THREE.Vector2`, too.

Comment: I tried to create another small square within as a hole. Defined it and called it in the triangulate function. It gives an error of `cannot read property next of undefined`. Here is the updated fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/rajur/n2kapkn3/3/. Will appreciate if you could let me know where I am going wrong. Thanks @Mugen87

Comment: As I said before, the second parameter of ` THREE.ShapeUtils.triangulateShape` is an array of holes. Not an array of `Vector2`. Here is a working exmaple: ` https://jsfiddle.net/n2kapkn3/4/ . Please have a look in the source code of `three.js` before asking more questions like this.